# Time series data aggregation per similar snapshots

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I have a cassandra table defined like below:

```
create table if not exists test(
    id int,
    readDate timestamp,
    totalreadings text,
    readings text,
    PRIMARY KEY(meter_id, date)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(date desc);
```

The reading contains the map of all snapshots of data collected at regular intervals (30 minutes) along with aggregated data for full day.

The data would like below :

```
id=8, readDate=Tue Dec 20 2016, totalreadings=220.0, readings={0=9.0, 1=0.0, 2=9.0, 3=5.0, 4=2.0, 5=7.0, 6=1.0, 7=3.0, 8=9.0, 9=2.0, 10=5.0, 11=1.0, 12=1.0, 13=2.0, 14=4.0, 15=4.0, 16=7.0, 17=7.0, 18=5.0, 19=4.0, 20=9.0, 21=6.0, 22=8.0, 23=4.0, 24=6.0, 25=3.0, 26=5.0, 27=7.0, 28=2.0, 29=0.0, 30=8.0, 31=9.0, 32=1.0, 33=8.0, 34=9.0, 35=2.0, 36=4.0, 37=5.0, 38=4.0, 39=7.0, 40=3.0, 41=2.0, 42=1.0, 43=2.0, 44=4.0, 45=5.0, 46=3.0, 47=1.0}]]
id=8, readDate=Tue Dec 21 2016, totalreadings=221.0, readings={0=9.0, 1=0.0, 2=9.0, 3=5.0, 4=2.0, 5=7.0, 6=1.0, 7=3.0, 8=9.0, 9=2.0, 10=5.0, 11=1.0, 12=1.0, 13=2.0, 14=4.0, 15=4.0, 16=7.0, 17=7.0, 18=5.0, 19=4.0, 20=9.0, 21=6.0, 22=8.0, 23=4.0, 24=6.0, 25=3.0, 26=5.0, 27=7.0, 28=2.0, 29=0.0, 30=8.0, 31=9.0, 32=1.0, 33=8.0, 34=9.0, 35=2.0, 36=4.0, 37=5.0, 38=4.0, 39=7.0, 40=3.0, 41=2.0, 42=1.0, 43=2.0, 44=4.0, 45=5.0, 46=3.0, 47=1.0}]]
id=8, readDate=Tue Dec 22 2016, totalreadings=219.0, readings={0=9.0, 1=0.0, 2=9.0, 3=5.0, 4=2.0, 5=7.0, 6=1.0, 7=3.0, 8=9.0, 9=2.0, 10=5.0, 11=1.0, 12=1.0, 13=2.0, 14=4.0, 15=4.0, 16=7.0, 17=7.0, 18=5.0, 19=4.0, 20=9.0, 21=6.0, 22=8.0, 23=4.0, 24=6.0, 25=3.0, 26=5.0, 27=7.0, 28=2.0, 29=0.0, 30=8.0, 31=9.0, 32=1.0, 33=8.0, 34=9.0, 35=2.0, 36=4.0, 37=5.0, 38=4.0, 39=7.0, 40=3.0, 41=2.0, 42=1.0, 43=2.0, 44=4.0, 45=5.0, 46=3.0, 47=1.0}]]
id=8, readDate=Tue Dec 23 2016, totalreadings=224.0, readings={0=9.0, 1=0.0, 2=9.0, 3=5.0, 4=2.0, 5=7.0, 6=1.0, 7=3.0, 8=9.0, 9=2.0, 10=5.0, 11=1.0, 12=1.0, 13=2.0, 14=4.0, 15=4.0, 16=7.0, 17=7.0, 18=5.0, 19=4.0, 20=9.0, 21=6.0, 22=8.0, 23=4.0, 24=6.0, 25=3.0, 26=5.0, 27=7.0, 28=2.0, 29=0.0, 30=8.0, 31=9.0, 32=1.0, 33=8.0, 34=9.0, 35=2.0, 36=4.0, 37=5.0, 38=4.0, 39=7.0, 40=3.0, 41=2.0, 42=1.0, 43=2.0, 44=4.0, 45=5.0, 46=3.0, 47=1.0}]]
```

The java pojo classes look like below:

```
public class Test{

    private int id;
    private Date readDate;
    private String totalreadings;   
    private Map<Integer, Double> readings;
//setters
//getters
}
```

I am trying to find last 4 days aggregated average of all reading per snapshot. So logically, i have 4 list for last 4 days Test object and each of them has a map containing reading across the intervals.

Is there a simple way to find aggregate of a similar snapshot entries across 4 days . For example , i want to aggregate specific data snapshots (1,2,3,4,5,6,etc) only not the total aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

After changing you table-structure a little bit the problem can be solved completely in Cassandra. - Mainly I have put your readings into a map.

```
create table  test(
  id int,
  readDate timestamp,
  totalreadings float,
  readings map<int,float>,
  PRIMARY KEY(id, readDate)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(readDate desc);
```

Now I entered a bit of your data using CQL:

```
insert into test (id,readDate,totalReadings, readings ) values (8 '2016-12-20', 220.0, {0:9.0, 1:0.0, 2:9.0, 3:5.0, 4:2.0, 5:7.0, 6:1.0, 7:3.0, 8:9.0, 9:2.0, 10:5.0, 11:1.0, 12:1.0, 13:2.0, 14:4.0, 15:4.0, 16:7.0, 17:7.0, 18:5.0, 19:4.0, 20:9.0, 21:6.0, 22:8.0, 23:4.0, 24:6.0, 25:3.0, 26:5.0, 27:7.0, 28:2.0, 29:0.0, 30:8.0, 31:9.0, 32:1.0, 33:8.0, 34:9.0, 35:2.0, 36:4.0, 37:5.0, 38:4.0, 39:7.0, 40:3.0, 41:2.0, 42:1.0, 43:2.0, 44:4.0, 45:5.0, 46:3.0, 47:1.0});
insert into test (id,readDate,totalReadings, readings ) values (8, '2016-12-21', 221.0,{0:9.0, 1:0.0, 2:9.0, 3:5.0, 4:2.0, 5:7.0, 6:1.0, 7:3.0, 8:9.0, 9:2.0, 10:5.0, 11:1.0, 12:1.0, 13:2.0, 14:4.0, 15:4.0, 16:7.0, 17:7.0, 18:5.0, 19:4.0, 20:9.0, 21:6.0, 22:8.0, 23:4.0, 24:6.0, 25:3.0, 26:5.0, 27:7.0, 28:2.0, 29:0.0, 30:8.0, 31:9.0, 32:1.0, 33:8.0, 34:9.0, 35:2.0, 36:4.0, 37:5.0, 38:4.0, 39:7.0, 40:3.0, 41:2.0, 42:1.0, 43:2.0, 44:4.0, 45:5.0, 46:3.0, 47:1.0});
```

To extract single values out of the map I created a User defined function (UDF). This UDF picks the right value aut of your map containing the readings. See [Cassandra docs on UDF](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDF.html) for more on UDFs. Note that UDFs are disabled in cassandra by default so you need to modify cassandra.yaml to include         `enable_user_defined_functions: true`

```
create function map_item(readings map<int,float>, idx int) called on null input returns float language java as ' return readings.get(idx);';
```

After creating the function you can calculate your average as

```
select avg(map_item(readings, 7)) from test where readDate > '2016-12-20' allow filtering;
```

which gives me:
    system.avg(betterconnect.map_item(readings, 7))
    -------------------------------------------------
                                               3

You may want to supply the date fort your where-clause and the index (7 in my example) as parameters from your application.